# How can I count a certain number of li tags using PHP?

Tags: php

I was wondering how can I count a certain number of li tags using PHP and when I reach a certain number do something? I'm using a `foreach` to output the list items.

Comment: You mean *parsing existing HTML* or *while outputting HTML*?

Comment: How are the `li` tags being generated? with a loop? Or are you explicitly stating those tags in the html part of the php code?

Comment: I think while outputting

Comment: @matrix see below for my answer. The problem is I don't know the exact nature of how you're displaying your html code in the foreach. So my solution is an abstracted form of the actual answer. You'll have to relate it back to how it's implemented in your actual code.

Comment: -1: No source code and highly ambiguous question led to at least two answers for a question you weren't actually asking. If you [edit] your post to make it more clear what you're after, I'll happily remove my downvote. Further advice on asking questions can be found at http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2):

Simplest would probably be:

```
$count = substr_count($html , "<li>");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 0;
foreach (…) {
    echo '<li>';
    $i++;
    if ($i > $certainNumber) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See below as per your statement that a foreach is involved. This is an abstracted form of the answer seeing as I don't exactly know how your foreach relates to the displaying of the actual HTML, so you'll have to relate this back to your actual code.

```
$c = 0;

foreach($html as $html_line)
    if (strpos($html_line, '<li>'))
        $c++;

// $c is equal to the number of li's in your html code.
```